# Getting Runtime Errors while Sending and Consuming Message Using Spring Boot and ApacheMQ

Tags: java, spring, maven

M using Spring Boot with ActiveMQ to send and Receive Messages. Please help
 I have 3 classes in my MAVEN Project

```
    1. SampleActiveMQApplication 

    package hello;

    import javax.jms.Queue;

    import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;

    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableJms
    public class SampleActiveMQApplication {

        @Bean
        public Queue queue() 
        {
            return new ActiveMQQueue("welcome.queue");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SampleActiveMQApplication.class, args);
        }

    }
```

M using Spring Boot with ActiveMQ to send and Receive Messages. Please help
 I have 3 classes in my MAVEN Project

```
    2.  Consumer

    package hello;


    import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class Consumer {

        @JmsListener(destination = "welcome.queue")
        public void receiveQueue(String text) {
            System.out.println(text);
        }

    }
```

M using Spring Boot with ActiveMQ to send and Receive Messages. Please help
 I have 3 classes in my MAVEN Project

```
    3. Producer

    package hello;


    import javax.jms.Queue;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
    import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class Producer implements CommandLineRunner {

        @Autowired
        private JmsMessagingTemplate jmsMessagingTemplate;

        @Autowired
        private Queue queue;

        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            send("Sample message");
            System.out.println("Message was sent to the Queue");
        }

        public void send(String msg) {
            this.jmsMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(this.queue, msg);
        }

    }
```

M getting error  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/GenericApplicationListener class not found error

4. pom.xml

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <groupId>ApacheMQBoot</groupId>
     <artifactId>ApacheMQBoot</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <properties>    
       <!-- Spring version -->
       <spring-framework.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>    
       <!-- ActiveMQ version -->
       <activemq.version>5.10.0</activemq.version>
     </properties>


       <parent>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
           <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
       </parent>

       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
           </dependency>


       <!-- Spring aritifacts -->

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>

       <!-- <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
       </dependency> -->


       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
         <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
       </dependency>  

       <!-- ActiveMQ Artifacts -->
       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
         <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
         <version>${activemq.version}</version>
       </dependency>
     </dependencies> 

     <!-- Using JDK 1.7 for compiling -->
     <build>
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.5.1</version>
           <configuration>
             <source>1.8</source>
             <target>1.8</target>
           </configuration>
         </plugin>
       </plugins>
     </build>
   </project>
   ```

ERRORS which m getting is dis

////

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:414)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:394)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:385)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:263)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:237)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
            at hello.SampleActiveMQApplication.main(SampleActiveMQApplication.java:22)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/GenericApplicationListener
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:407)
            ... 7 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListener**
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class/interface `org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListener` is available from spring 4.2. You have to change to newer Version of spring.

See the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/GenericApplicationListener.html)

Comment: Now I am getting this error                                                                     1. org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsListenerContainerFactory' defined in class path resource                                                                                                 2. Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 3. Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setAutoStartup(Z)V  Please Help me Out on this

Comment: @PriyankaTaneja Looks like you have incompatible jars in your project

Comment: I have attached my pom.xml here can u Please guide me which jar is incompatible because M completely new to this thing thanks...

Comment: @PriyankaTaneja for this i need the complete stacktrace

Comment: Ok Thanks  a lot I will try to fix it.

Comment: Hi @Jens  I changed version it is working fine but I am not getting message in Queues at localhost:8161/.... Please Reply

Comment: I dont have any error. Can you Please check my code once whether its correct or not?

Comment: which version did you had to solve org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setAutoStartup(Z)